# How to apply descending order in order by case?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I have a simple table and I want to sort it by specific rules. My desired output looks like this:

```
 PERSON_THIRD_BUF
 PERSON_TWO_BUF
 PERSON_TWO_BUF_11
 PERSON_TWO_BUF_10
 PERSON_TWO_BUF_9
 PERSON_TWO_BUF_8
 PERSON_TWO_BUF_7
 PERSON_TWO_BUF_6
 PERSON_TWO_BUF_5
 PERSON_TWO_BUF_4
 PERSON_TWO_BUF_3
 PERSON_TWO_BUF_2
 PERSON_TWO_BUF_1
```

So  `PERSON_THIRD_BUF` should be the first, `PERSON_TWO_BUF` should be the second, and `PERSON_TWO_BUF_*` should be in descending order:

I've managed to sort `PERSON_TWO_BUF`, `PERSON_THIRD_BUF`, however I could not figure out how to sort `PERSON_TWO_BUF_*` in descending order.

```
DECLARE @t table(col1 VARCHAR(50));


insert into @t 
values
( N'PERSON_TWO_BUF' ), 
( N'PERSON_THIRD_BUF' ), 
( N'PERSON_TWO_BUF_1' ), 
( N'PERSON_TWO_BUF_2' ), 
( N'PERSON_TWO_BUF_3' ), 
( N'PERSON_TWO_BUF_4' ), 
( N'PERSON_TWO_BUF_5' ), 
( N'PERSON_TWO_BUF_6' ), 
( N'PERSON_TWO_BUF_7' ), 
( N'PERSON_TWO_BUF_8' ), 
( N'PERSON_TWO_BUF_9' ), 
( N'PERSON_TWO_BUF_10' ), 
( N'PERSON_TWO_BUF_11' )

SELECT * FROM @t
ORDER BY CASE
      WHEN COL1 = 'PERSON_THIRD_BUF' THEN 0
    WHEN COL1 = 'PERSON_TWO_BUF' THEN 1
    WHEN COL1 LIKE 'PERSON_TWO_BUF_%' THEN 3
    END
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible option is the following `ORDER BY` clause (based on the attempt from the question):

```
SELECT * FROM @t
ORDER BY 
   CASE
      WHEN COL1 = 'PERSON_THIRD_BUF' THEN 0
      WHEN COL1 = 'PERSON_TWO_BUF' THEN 1
      WHEN COL1 LIKE 'PERSON_TWO_BUF_%' THEN 2
      ELSE 3
   END,
   TRY_CONVERT(int, REPLACE(col1, 'PERSON_TWO_BUF_', '')) DESC
```

Comment: brilliant, I will accept it in 3 minutes! Thanks! Have a nice day! :)

Comment: I hope you never have a PERSON_FOURTH_BUF